# Resharper structural find and replace with objects

Tags: c#, resharper

I use a library which provides a custom fluent implementation for `string.Format`. The idea is to replace the common format construct with one that reads in a more natural way like this:

```
// From this
string.Format("some format string with {0} parameter", 1);
string.Format(SomeConstant, "abc");
// To this
"some format string with {0} parameter".Format(1);
SomeConstant.Format("abc");
```

I was trying to setup a simple structural find and replace pattern in Resharper to help me deal with those inside my code base. I noticed that if I set the format string parameter as an *Argument Placeholder matching exactly one argument* and the list of arguments uses entity objects (like a Person object), the previous example would turn into:

```
// Note that this is the System.String class and not the original format string
String.Format(someEntity);
```

If the entity is first converted to a string, then it matches properly and keeps the format string as I would expect.

```
SomeConstant.Format(someEntity.ToString());
```

I had to use an *Expression Placeholder with an expression type of `System.String`* to properly match the first parameter.

Is this a bug or is there something that I am not understanding in this behavior? Why would the type of the second argument influence the match of the first argument? I have a feeling that I might be misunderstanding how *Argument Placeholders* are working...

NB: Using Resharper 9.0 Update 1

EDIT: As requested, here is the search pattern details:

Search Pattern: `String.Format($format$, $args$)`
Replace Pattern: `$format$.Format($args)`
format: `Argument Placeholder, matching exactly one argument`
args: `Argument Placeholder, matching at least one argument`

Comment: I think you need to expand on your question. Without seeing the search or replace patterns, and knowing what the placeholders are, it's very tricky to see if it's behaving as it should.